# Styling the media object with CSS flexbox

Tags: css

I'm trying to improve my CSS skills. A few years ago Nicolas Gallagher designed with floats a few variation of the media object as explained by Nicole Sullivan. Here's his HTML:

```
<div class="imgblock cf"> 
    <div class="img img-medium"> 
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt=""> 
     </div> 
     <div class="content"> 
        A little bit of content ok content
     </div> 
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.imgblock {

}

.imgblock .img {
    float:left;
    margin:0 5px 0 0;
}

.imgblock .img-medium {
    margin-right:10px;
}

.imgblock .img img {
    display:block;
}
```

You can check the whole code here: http://jsfiddle.net/necolas/rZvEF/

Following Philip Walton (you can check his "Solved by Flexbox website") as an exercise I did the same with flexbox. The HTML:

```
<div class="media">
  <div class="media__img">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
  </div>
  <div class="media__body">
    <p>A little bit of content ok content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.media {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.media__img {
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.media__body {
  flex: 1;
}
```

you can find the entire code here: https://jsfiddle.net/luc4leone/wqqkwhou/

Any comments to improve the code, or to point out mistakes I did, or just to comment on OOCSS would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't get the problem. What exactly is the question?

Comment: Hi Hashem, I'd like to know if you think the CSS or HTML can be improved. For example is it OK to wrap the img and p tag with divs? I think these additional elements help to make the media object reusable. This is what Gallegher did, but Walton did not. Another example is the class .vertical-align that I added to center the text in the first media object: I'm not sure if it's worth it to add a class just for one rule.